# Windows 10 keeps forgetting notification sounds

Tags: windows-10, notifications, system-sounds

I've configured Windows 10 to play a certain sound when an application starts or ends. It works fine, but next time I switch on my computer, these sounds have been removed.

This worked flawlessly in Windows 7 and did work fine in Windows 10 for a few weeks. It's just the last week or so that it's started to "forget" the sound setting.

The standard sounds are retained, i.e. login, logout, warning message etc. Perhaps it reverts to defaults?

What might be causing this and how might I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to change the sounds in the Registry to see if they retain? Follow Option 3 [change sounds windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5838-sounds-change-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I've tried that now. I noticed that the sound I want was already present under the `.Modified` key.

Anyway, I'll leave it like this and see what happens with a few reboots, later.

Comment: Are these sounds stored locally, or on a network drive?

Comment: @LPChip: It's actually one of the standard sounds that Windows uses by default (the one for emptying the garbage bin). So, yes, it's stored locally.

Comment: The sound is still there today. Looking good! If it stays there for a few more days I'll conclude that setting it in the registry worked. Question remains why it does NOT work to set it via the sound configuration dialog.

Comment: Still works. @NetworkKingPin's suggestion was apparently the right one. Feel free to write it as an answer instead of a comment and I'll mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @kJell Rilbe said his settings kept.

Here is the answer just in case the site removes the content.

> 1. Type **regedit** in the search box <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) on your Start menu or taskbar, and press Enter to open Registry Editor.
>
> **2.** In Registry Editor, navigate to the location below. (see screenshot below)
>
> **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps**

[image]

> **3.** In the left pane, expand open the **.Default** (Windows sounds), **Explorer** (File Explorer sounds), and/or **sapisvr** (Windows Speech Recognition sounds) keys. (see screenshot above)
>
> **4.** In the left pane under the **.Default**, **Explorer**, or **sapisvr** key, click/tap on the subkey (ex: Nofication.Mail under .Default) for the event you want to change the sound of. (see screenshot above)
>
> **5.** In the left pane under the selected sound event (ex: Nofication.Mail), select the **.Current** subkey, and double click/tap on **(Default)** in the right pane. (see screenshot below)
>   [image]
>
> **6.** Type in the full path of the unblocked **.wav** file you want to be applied to the event, and click/tap on **OK**. (see screenshot below)

[image]

> **7.** Repeat **step 4** above if you would like to change the sound for any other event.
>
> **8.** When finished, you can close Registry Editor if you like.

Quoted Material from [TenForums](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5838-sounds-change-windows-10-a.html)